# error in hive query while using windowing

Tags: hive

While doing this

```
select 
  first_value(id) over(partition by id rows between 1 precending and 1 following) 
  from college;
```

query error is

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:43 cannot recognize input near
>   'precending' 'and' '1' in window frame boundary

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you need to add `order by` and ordering column before `rows between`. For more information https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Comment: Is there a typo precending? - it should be preceding